# How to access a variable which is declared in some other function?

Tags: python

```
      def main():
                 x=2
      def cool():
                 y=4

nonlocal x
print (x)
```

It is showing an error as --nonlocal x is a invalid syntax--.And if I dont declare it as nonlocal it says undefined x. So, how do i acess a variable which is in some other function ?Now how do i access x variable  which is defined at main().

Comment: nonlocal is new to python 3 and it is for accessing variables from the outer scope (non-global). http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: ok how do i access if it is python 2.5.5?

Comment: nonlocal is not for what you think it is. why do you need to access the variable anyway and not just return the value?

Comment: Its not any project cularis Iam a beginner Iam expermenting with it.I am learning global concepts, so In the tutorial he defined a variable outside the main and accesed it in the function using global but i wanted to make it in reverse but its not working.

Comment: I wanted to define it in function and access it outside )

Comment: You simply cannot, because the variable is initialized the moment you enter into the function and gets destroyed as soon as the you get out of the function.
You can do what do so to if the function cool is nested inside main, but this is perhaps not what you want to do.

Comment: But in python 3 you can access a variable in one function which is defined in some other function right but is there no way to do it the 2.5.5 version of Python

Comment: @niko, that change allows to assign to a outer functions in an inner function. It applies if one function is defined inside another. It doesn't let you access any more variables then you couldn't access before. It only lets you change ones that you couldn't change before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

You shouldn't. Doing so would just make it hard to read code because code from anywhere could read and modify your variables. By keeping access restricted to the one function it is easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Once you start needing attributes on a function, turn it into a *[functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object)*:

```
class MainFactory(object):
    def __call__(self):
        self.x = 4

main = MainFactory() # Create the function-like object main
main()               # call it
print main.x         # inspect internal attributes
```

A functor in python is simply a normal object whose class implements the special `__call__` method. It can have an `__init__` method as well, in which you may pre-set the values of attributes if you wish. Then you can create different "flavours" of your functor by supplying different arguments when instantiating:

```
class MainFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, parameter=1):
        self.parameter = parameter

    def __call__(self):
        self.x = 4 * self.parameter
```

Now `main = MainFactory(2); main()` will have `main.x` set to 8.

Obviously, you can keep unimportant variables of the function inaccessible by simply using local variables instead of attributes of `self`:

```
   def __call__(self):
       # i and p are not accessible from outside, self.x is
       for i in range(10):
           p = i ** self.parameter
           self.x += p
```

Comment: While this is an interesting technique, you've missed the OP's actual question, which is a beginner-level misunderstanding about the nature of Python's scopes.

Comment: @Ned I perfectly understood the OP's question. Already present comments explained that it was not possible to do it the way he wanted to, I did not see the need to repeat it. My answer is the only one that shows how to do exactly what OP _wanted_, though not in the way he tried to do it: call a function without arguments, then access variable used inside function afterwards, without using globals. I think the downvote was uncalled for.

Answer (score 1):

You do not. The variables local to a function only exist while that function is running; so once main has returned, its x does not exist. This also ties in to the fact that a separate call to the function gets a separate variable.

What you describe is a bit like reading the value of a static variable in C. The difference with static variables is that they're independent of the call; they still exist, and that makes most functions that use them non-reentrant. Sometimes this is emulated in Python by [adding a default argument with a mutable value](http://www.ferg.org/projects/python_gotchas.html#contents_item_6), with the same downsides.

In CPython, you actually can find out what the local variables of a pure Python function are by inspecting its code object, but their values will only exist in the call itself, normally on a call stack.

```
def func():
     x=2
import dis
print func.__code__.co_varnames
dis.disassemble(func.__code__)
```

yields:

```
('x',)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

So x is actually local variable 0.

I would suggest looking up a debugger for details on call stack inspection.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0
def main():
    global x
    x = 2 # accesses global x

main()
print x  # prints 2
```

Comment: This isn't exactly answering niko's question, is it? You've changed `x` into a global variable.